# Contextmenu and DragnDrop on right click using jquery easyUI

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-easyui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I have integrated jQuery easyUI plugin for Treegrid (editable and drag n drop feature). All the features has been successfully implemented. There's one feature of behaving as "When a user right click it should the "Custom Context menu" that is done, but at the same time if user right click and drag the row then it should allow user to drop the same row within treegrid.

In my case it allows when I use left click, but when trying the same with right click and drag - nothing happens, it will just show me the "ContextMenu" of the row which drop into.

If anybody knows the solution then please let me know at the earliest.

jQuery EasyUI 1.4.2 
treegrid.js 
treegrid-dnd.js

These are the jquery which have been integrated.